# Micronaut application is not registered with eureka-server

Tags: micronaut, netflix-eureka

Micronaut application is not registered with eureka-server if "micronaut-serde-jackson" dependency is added.

micronaut CLI command to create project
mn create-app --build=maven --jdk=17 --lang=java --test=junit --features=discovery-eureka,graalvm,serialization-jackson example.micronaut.bookcatalogue

11:10:22.287 [main] INFO  i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Reading bootstrap environment configuration
11:10:25.048 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 4499ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
11:10:35.173 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN  i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

Trying to connect micronaut application with eureka-server.